# Using numpy to combine data sets with different time base

Tags: python, numpy, time-series

I am trying to analyse data from several thousand sensors. They all provide me with data that comes in as follows:

```
Sensor 76, t0, [r0,...,rN]
Sensor 15, t1, [r0,...,rN]
...
Sensor N, tN, [r0,...,rN]
```

where `tN > ... > t1 > t0` (i.e. time-sorted) and `rX` is just a count over a fixed interval (1.6384 ms). For all practical purposes they are set of histograms with counts vs. time with `t0, t1,...` being the left edge of the histogram.

The problem I am running into is trying to rebin the data into a global histogram. That is create a count vs. absolute time histogram for every sensor. The bins of this new histogram are supposed to be 2 ms long. Currently, I am using the following code to fill this global histogram:

```
s0 = sensor.utc # left time edge of sensor count
s1 = sensor.utc + self.config.data_bin_size # right time edge of sensor count
t0 = self.config.absolute_time + array_index * self.config.time_sync_bin_size # left time edge of absolute bin 
t1 = t0 + self.config.time_sync_bin_size # right time edge of absolute bin 
ib = 0 # Index in original array

sensor_num = self.sensor_mapping[sensor.id]["sensor_number"]

while ib < len(sensor.scalers):
    u0 = max(s0, t0)
    u1 = min(s1, t1)
    self.global_bins[array_index][1][DOM_num] += float(u1 - u0) / float(s1 - s0) * sensor.scalers[ib] # putting things into the global histogram
    if u1 == t1:
        array_index += 1
        t0 = t1
        t1 += self.config.time_sync_bin_size
    if u1 == s1:
        ib += 1
        s0 = s1
        s1 += self.config.data_bin_size
```

This seems like a very un-numpy like. I am looping over certain array indices repeatedly because they are split between absolute time bins. Does anybody have a idea how to improve this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the Pandas library?

Comment: I have. I havent been able to find something that handles this case well. All examples I could find did not have data that was disjointed in time or replaced with NAN instead of being able to combine them